# How to combine theme.breakpoints on react?

Tags: reactjs

I need some configuration on my app to be resposnive.
For example I used a component SearchIcon from material-ui and I want to adjust it on the screen:

```
style = themes => {
 iconSearch: {
  [theme.breakpoints.up('sm') && theme.breakpoints.down('md')]: {
    margin: 14%
  }
  [theme.breakpoints.up('md') && theme.breakpoints.down('lg')]: {
    margin: 8%
  }
}
```

But this does not take into consideration to make margin 14% when `min-width=576px` and `max-width=768px` and also for the second option. How to fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was answered by [oliviertassinari](https://github.com/oliviertassinari) on the [MUI Github repo](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/8712)

> So both solutions should be working. But be aware, this is untested code.

```
style = themes => {
 iconSearch: {
  [`${theme.breakpoints.up('sm')} and ${theme.breakpoints.down('md')}`]: {
    margin: 14%
  }
}


style = themes => {
 iconSearch: {
  [theme.breakpoints.between('sm', 'md')]: {
    margin: 14%
  }
}
```